# I am trying to return a class datatype using Hashmap get() but gives me error saying "must return value of type". Please advise

Tags: java

My return value for method `getVal` complains with the error:

> must return value of type test1.

I am not sure why would it complain about return type as I assume `get` would give you the value for the corresponding key. Please help me understand this logic.

```
public class test1 {
    //There is some class named test1
    public test1() { //Default Constructor
    }

    public test1 getVal(String name) {
        return sample.get(name);
    }
}

public class test {
    public test() {
        HashMap<String, test1> sample = new Hashmap<>();
        sample.put("Name", new test1());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always start your classes with an uppercase letter.

Comment: `sample` in class `test` is locally scoped to method `test()` so the `getVal` is not referring to it - you must have another `sample` variable defined somewhere.

Comment: First of all, `sample` map isn't visible for **test1** class (its scope is only inside the constructor) and *"must return value of type test1"* means that the provided code in your question is not the same code that you've tried to execute. Can you provide more details maybe? from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your HashMap named `sample` is not visible in `getVal` method.  You can add it as parameter to that method or make the HashMap `sample` visible to the `getVal` method.